# Why does gaps between tiles in an orthogonal tilemap cocos2d game appear when running on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to make a tilemap-based game using cocos2d 2.1 and Tiled 0.9.1. The game runs perfectly on the simulator, but I have gaps (artifact lines) between the tiles when running on the device.

Please see the screenshot.

[image: Gaps between tilemap]

The diff is the difference (made in photoshop) between the original tile (taken straight from the png of the tileset) and the tile as rendered by cocos2d. As you can see, in simulator they are 100% identical. However, on the device it seems that cocos2d shrinks the tile texture vertically by just a little bit. The 1 pixel stripe is actually the texture above the troublesome tile in the tileset.

Any idea what caused this and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using shaders? I mean obviously somewhere your application is, but I am not familiar with your particular library. If you have written your own GLSL shaders, the first thing that comes to mind is the precision of your texture coordinates. Next, would be the texture wrap mode, but I think the simulator and actual hardware would be pretty consistent in this respect - precision is the thing where they would differ most.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman no, I'm not using any custom shaders, so all shaders are from cocos2d I presume.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman btw, the simulator and device does have some precision differences. For example, a particular timer on one is 64-bit floating point while the other was 32-bit floating point, and it caused problems on my code by assuming it was always 32-bit. However if there is indeed a precision problem on this problem, I really have no idea where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not certain why this happens on devices only, but you should read in ccConfig.h for parameter CC_FIX_ARTIFACTS_BY_STRECHING_TEXEL. This in itself is a bad kludge, but it gives you a hint as to where to look.

Basically, you should make certain that all your positions are on an exact pixel boundary, ie on non-retina devices cast them to int, and on retina devices round to the nearest exact multiple of .5.  Best way to ensure that is to make all your textures w,h even numbers ... the onus is on the artist for anything that will not move. If you move things, and the final position is calculated (for example in a ccTouches move,end), make certain you do this rounding there.  Beware of batch nodes : the node itself, and all its children should be on pel boundary.

Comment: OK, I'm accepting this as an answer because it fixes the gap problem, even though it seems to stretch the texture larger than it should be. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

While using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19768044/2246380) In my case enabling `CC_FIX_ARTIFACTS_BY_STRECHING_TEXEL` was not enough.

I also added the following code to `AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()` function and rounded values passed to `setPosition(x, y)` function to nearest int.

```
Director::getInstance()->setProjection(Director::Projection::_2D);
```

I use `cocos2d-x 3.4.`